# org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: Could not interpret dot-ident : brandId

Tags: hibernate

I'm learning Hibernate but I keep getting the following error when I try to filter with the brandId:

> GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Jersey Web Application] en el contexto con ruta [/restAppJSON] lanzó la excepción [org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [from products where brandId = 5]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser] con causa raíz
>   org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: Could not interpret dot-ident : brandId
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer$BaseLocalSequencePart.resolvePathPart(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:225)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitDotIdentifierSequence(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2725)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2662)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:149)
>       at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathFragmentContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2947)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitPath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2654)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitPath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:149)
>       at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$PathContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2745)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:761)
>       at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$PathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5232)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEqualityPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1144)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEqualityPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:149)
>       at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$EqualityPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:4310)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1070)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:149)
>       at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:4086)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpec(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:400)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:262)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:214)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:161)
>       at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:47)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$1(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:621)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:114)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:619)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:603)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:97)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.createQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at com.edo.showroom.hibernate.DAO.ProductDAO.getProductsByBrand(ProductDAO.java:21)
>       at com.edo.showroom.service.ProductService.getProductsByBrand(ProductService.java:13)
>       at com.edo.showroom.resources.Products.getProductsByBrand(Products.java:20)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

these are my 2 tables in mysql

CREATE TABLE `brands` (
  `brandId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brandName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brandId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `brandid_UNIQUE` (`brandId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brandId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  KEY `brandid_idx` (`brandId`),
  CONSTRAINT `brandid` FOREIGN KEY (`brandId`) REFERENCES `brands` (`brandId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

These are my entity classes:

```
@Entity(name = "products")
@Table(name = "products")
public class ProductEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "productId")
private int productId;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = BrandEntity.class)
@JoinColumn()
private BrandEntity brandEntity;

@Column(name = "productname")
private String productName;

@Column(name = "category")
private String category;

@Column(name = "cost")
private double cost;

public ProductEntity() {
}
```

+getters and setters

```
@Entity(name = "brands")
@Table(name = "brands")
public class BrandEntity {
    @Id
@Column(name = "brandId")
private Integer brandId;

@Column(name = "brandName")
private String brandName;

public BrandEntity() {
}
```

My DAO class is this:

```
public class ProductDAO {

SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(ProductEntity.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(BrandEntity.class).buildSessionFactory();

public List<ProductEntity> getProductsByBrand(int brandId) {
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String stmt = "from products where brandId = " + brandId;
    List<ProductEntity> productList = session.createQuery(stmt).getResultList();
    return productList;
}
```

}

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

OK i found out what is the problem, i used hibernate-core 6 Alpha release. I switched to 5.4.12.Final and everything is executing without any problems

Answer (score -1):

you are searching the below in DAO class

*current code*
from **products** where brandId = " + brandId;

*It should be*
from **brands** where brandId = " + brandId;

these kind of error comes under logical user training error
kind of spelling mistake

Comment: Considering the CREATE TABLE products schema the brandId is configured as a constraint which make it accessible in the query. If the column is not present in a queried table, the error would've be unknow column 'brandId' or something similar.